# HTML file input resulting in mixed up $_FILES variable

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form with several file inputs, like so:

```
<form action="/form/update" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <input type="file" name="FormName[File1]" >
    <input type="file" name="FormName[File2]" >
    ...
</form>
```

However, when I submit the form, the `$_FILES` php variable looks like the keys are mixed up.

```
Array
(
    [Client] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [File1] => avatar.png
                    [File2] => logo.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [File1] => image/png
                    [File2] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [File1] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpE97D.tmp
                    [File2] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpE97E.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [File1] => 0
                    [File2] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [File1] => 17719
                    [File2] => 14117
                )

        )

)
```

Is this normal behavior for fields with array names? Shouldn't the structure for `$_FILES` be `$_FILES['FormName']['File1']['name']`, and not `$_FILES['FormName']['name']['File1']`?

Comment: Why are you using `name="formName[file1]"` and not just `name="file1"`?

Comment: @acupajoe, to match the Yii2 backend. It makes it easier to load the form data into the models if I follow their naming convention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing multi-dimensional $\_FILES array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464893/processing-multi-dimensional-files-array)

Comment: There's a [sample function to rearrange the array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#109958) listed in the comments of the php.net documentation page. Also see [Uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: That's perfectly fine for that.

Answer (score 1):

"Is this normal behavior for fields with array names?"

[Yes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

> When the above form is submitted, the arrays $_FILES['userfile'], $_FILES['userfile']['name'], and $_FILES['userfile']['size'] will be initialized... Each of these will be a numerically indexed array of the appropriate values for the submitted files.

The same would apply for a non-numerically indexed array. If it weren't this way, you couldn't loop through the content of `$_FILES` and get predictable output.